# Where to keep wrap.sh for for memory debug in Android

Tags: android, memory, java-native-interface, malloc, android-source

I want to do memory profiling using android malloc debug for my system application which loads a native shared library. I am interested in memory debugging for native library (*.so). For memory debug to work, application should start without zygote forking. That's why I need to keep a wrap.sh. Various articles says about the relative path in Android studio but I am compiling source through AOSP code. My Apk resides in "/system/priv-app/" folder and .so library resides in "/system/lib64/".

My questions where do I need to keep wrap.sh file. Should it be wrapped inside apk or I can keep inside "/system/privapp/MyApp/lib/arm64-v8a" path.

Answer (score 0):

Android documents explain where to put wrap.sh in the build folder and where it will be in the apk folder.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/wrap-script
[image]